# outlook powershell - incrementing time for meeting start time?

Tags: vba, powershell, outlook

Currently i'm hacking together a powershell script that I'd like to have the ability to send meeting invites out while incrementing the time of the meeting (e.g. if first invite is sent for 9:00 meeting, I'd like the second meeting to be sent out for 9:30).

So far below is what I have. I can read the list of emails from the textfile and send the invites, however Im having problems adding time to the meeting (AddMinutes() doesnt seem to work on the meeting invite start time)

```
$emails = get-content emails.txt
$olAppointmentItem = 1 
$o = new-object -comobject outlook.application
foreach ($element in $emails){
   $a = $o.CreateItem($olAppointmentItem)
   $a.meetingstatus=[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olMeetingStatus]::olMeeting
   $a.meetingstatus.olMeeting
   $a.Start = [datetime]::ParseExact("09:00","hh:mm",$null)
   $a.Duration = 30
   $a.Subject = "Test Meeting"
   $a.Body = "Just a test, please accept, then delete."
   $a.Location = "Here"
   $a.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
   $a.ReminderSet = $True
   $a.recipients.add($element)
   $a.ForceUpdateToAllAttendees =$True
   $a.send()
   $a.Start.AddMinutes(+30)
}
$result = $a.Save()
```

Comment: The O in olMeetingStatus should be capitalized, so it will be [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMeetingStatus]. Most of the time in PowerShell, case does not matter, but in this case, it does because it is referring to a C# namespace. I wasted an hour pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the meeting would not send. I'll try to edit the answer, but in case it is not accepted, I wanted to comment here.

Answer (score 0):

`.AddMinutes()` works on a `[DateTime]` object and I would have to check what `.Start` accepts or if you are able to read from it. In theory `$a.Start.AddMinutes(+30)` would just return a `[datetime]` object similar to `Thursday, September 25, 2014 9:30:00 AM`. You are not assigning it to anything.

A basic approach to this would be to save the first time into its own variable

```
$900am = [datetime]::ParseExact("09:00","hh:mm",$null)
$a.Start = $900am
```

Then down below where you attempt to change this you could do this:

```
$a.Start = $900am.AddMinutes(30)
```

Or not bother with the variable and just call the method `ParseExact` again.

```
$a.Start = ([datetime]::ParseExact("09:00","hh:mm",$null)).AddMinutes(30)
```

I dont know if your logic holds so i am going to have to test that but the above will certainly help with your time manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It appears that it will add 30 minutes to the LAST invite sent to the individual in emails.txt, however it won't apply the 30 minutes to the other appointments. I'm new to powershell (as you can tell from the code), so Im wonder.. is foreach the best method for me to do this?